# File 'english-ieee.lbx' not found! Ignoring mapping 'english' -> 'english-ieee'

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I believe an update has been made on `biblatex` package in recent past. The following code gives `Package biblatex Warning: File 'english-ieee.lbx' not found! Ignoring mapping 'english' -> 'english-ieee` warning which was not there a few weeks ago. Any suggestion on how to remove it please?

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdfLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
    volume = "322",
    number = "10",
    pages = "891--921",
    year = "1905",
    doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage[%
    style=ieee,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    sortcites=true,
    natbib=true,
    backend=bibtex, 
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Einstein journal paper~\cite{einstein}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Update** `biblatex-ieee` version 1.3a 2019-06-19 includes the code changes explained below and thus does not issue the warning any more.
>
> If you are bothered by the warning consider updating your TeX distribution.
>
> The rest of the answer is kept for historical interest.

The warning is benign and can be ignored.

Since version 1.3 `biblatex-ieee` comes with a Hungarian localisation file, see https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/pull/40 (and the long discussion in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/717 for background). This file is loaded with a generic `\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-ieee}` and not with a specific `\DeclareLanguageMapping{magyar}{magyar-ieee}`. That means that all languages try to resolve the language mapping, but all languages except `magyar` fail to find a corresponding `-ieee.lbx` file.

It has been discussed whether or not this warning should be downgraded to an info message, but when this last was suggested I thought it more useful to have this message be a warning. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/745. At the time I thought that such a situation would not occur as often since I did not really expect styles with single localisation files, plus those styles could use an explicit mapping to avoid the warning. If this is a big problem, we may have to reconsider this decision. Comments are appreciated.

If you are very bothered by the warning you can suppress it with the `silence` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{biblatex}{File 'english-ieee.lbx'}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

**Update**

A while ago https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/pull/43 was merged into `biblatex-ieee` and so the style now uses an explicit

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{magyar}{magyar-ieee}
```

instead of the catch-all

```
\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-ieee}
```

<strike>In the next release of `biblatex-ieee` the warning should be gone.</strike> The warning is gone in v1.3a (2019-06-19) of `biblatex-ieee`.

Comment: Now I can understand why I received such a warning nowadays which were never there. However, I could not understand why it should be merged only with `magyar` language, rather there should be a way to put `magyar` or other languages with a problem free inclusion on English language (in my opinion).

Comment: @Khaaba The Hungarian language needs special treatments of some fields that made it necessary to ship a `magyar-ieee.lbx` with `biblatex-ieee` (you can read more about that in the links mentioned in the answer). As I explained the person who implemented this used the generic all-language mapping ``\DeclareLanguageMappingSuffix{-ieee}` instead of a language specific `\DeclareLanguageMapping{magyar}{magyar-ieee}` mapping.